# How to get all option values in a multiple select with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all options values of a multiple select with the following code.

```
var service_m = $("#SelectRight>option").map(function () { return $(this).val(); });
```

When I do this I only get [object Object] in return.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: how do you want to store those values? in an array? separated by comma? or what else?

Comment: I would like to have it separated by comma.

Comment: Is SelectRight the name of your select?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
var arr = [];
$("#SelectRight > option").each(function(){
   arr.push(this.value);
});
```

That will store all values in `arr` array.

If you want them to be a single string with comma separated, you can go further like this:

```
var str = arr.join(', ');
```

Answer (score 3):

`var optionArray = $.makeArray($("#SelectRight option"));`